# Connecting server to internet without port forwarding via vpn

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, iis

Due to restrictions I cannot port forward. I understand that I can use a VPN to overcome this restriction and have tried, but no luck so far.

I signed up for a dedicated package with an IP, the service people have told me that they have setup port forwarding from their end to our own server on ports 80 and 443.

On our local network, the sites works fine. On the internet though, when trying to access the VPN address using http, nothing happens. When using https, we get a certificate errors (which is somewhat expected). If using a browser that ignores the certificate errors then after bypassing the error nothing happens again.

I have tried both iis (which is what the site I hope to put online runs on) and xampp on port 80 and gotten the same results. The VPN provider claims the problem is on our end, as the fact that it shows the certificate error is proof they've configured correctly.

I know next to nothing about networking, so any help with figuring out what is wrong will be appreciated. How do I go about figuring out just where the problem is please?

I do know our isp put us on a dedicated IP we share with others, and we cannot do any port forwarding.

Comment: You should look at the presented cert - it will likely give you an indication what device isresponding si you know where the packets are landing up. (The cert name field is often very telling). You really havnt provided enogh info for us to help, like VPN protocol, where the VPN client runs etc.

Comment: @davigo, can you give me a list of the info you need? Thanks. I only know that  our machine, which I assume is the client in this case, is on a local network with a router that shares a public IP with other networks. Would posting the log from OpenVpn help? Also, will look into viewing the certificate.

Comment: I cant give you a full list of info I need because I dont know what I dont know. Providing vpn logs can help. A network diagram showing IP addresses and where the VPN client us running can help, and Apache logs may ir may not be yseful. ( its possible that the Apache is using virtualhisting bound to the LAN address, and needs to be modified to serve the same request more widely)